# Probability of winning roulette wheel

Tags: probability

[image]

### Try

Let $X$ be the number of first $n$ bets that we win. $X$ is binomial with $p= \frac{1}{38}$ and $n=?$

I knwo that that I need to find $P(X > 34 )$ and approximate with Normal, but how can we find our $n$ ?

Comment: Hint for the first part:  if you win even once you will have a profit.

Comment: I don't understand where $X>34$ comes from, nor why you think you have to determine $n.$  Isn't $n=34$ for part a, and $n=1000$ for part b?

Comment: The first task reads "you are winning after 34 **bets**" (_not_ wins). So if $X$ signifies your _wins_, $P(X > 34)$ can't be the right question.

Comment: a) you need to find $P(X\ge 1| n= 34)$ b) yes, when $n$ is large a binomial distribution begins to look like a normal distribution.  What is the mean and standard deviation.  With that information how do you find your probabilities?

Comment: Have you lost all 33 previous bets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rewards is $$35W-(N-W)=36W-N$$ where $W$ is the number of times you win out of $N$ game.

We have $W \sim Bin(N, \frac1{38}).$

Hence, for the first part, we are interested in

We are interested in $P(36W-N > 0)=P(W > \frac{N}{36}).$

For the first part $N=34$.

Hence $P(W> \frac{34}{36})=1-P(W=0)=1-(1-\frac1{38})^{34}$

For the second part $N=1000$,

$P(W > \frac{1000}{36})=P(W > 27.777)$

We can use normal approximation to estimate $W$ as $N(\frac{N}{38}, \frac{37N}{38^2})$ and approximate is as

\begin{align}
P\left( Z>\frac{27.5-\frac{N}{38}}{\sqrt{\frac{37N}{38^2}}}\right) &= P\left(  Z>\frac{38(27.5)-N}{\sqrt{37N}}\right) \\
&= P(Z > 0.23394386021)
\end{align}

where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.